# Laravel Display USD Product mysql Price exchanged from Bitcoin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have an liitle store with Products where all the Price are in Bitcoin also in Mysql Database in this formate:

```
{{$product->buyout*0.00000001}} @else {{$product->price*0.00000001}}
```

Now i want display the Bitcoin Price from database in USD live rate with Curl.

Whats the best method for it?

I have try it with this code,any other working ideas?:

```
<?php  
  $url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";

  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

  $rate = $data[1]["rate"];    
  $bitcoin_price = 0.008;    
  $usd_price = round( $bitcoin_price / $rate , 8 );
?>

<ul>
   <li>Price: <?=$bitcoin_price ?> BTC / <?=$usd_price ?> USD
</ul>
```